# Using RadWindow and referencing main page content that is within an AJAX panel

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radwindow

What would one way to handle updating a label within a radwindow that references the value of another control on the main page?
Assuming that the window is defined in a content template.  The main page has an ajax panel where the controls in question are located.  So the window onload method is called and appears to set the text of its label correctly (it can see the value of the main control), its just that the update isnt displayed in the window label.

**update**:
well, this might be one approach - use a seperate page and set it as the value of the navigateurl property on the window, then pass in values set in the code behind, via the querystring as in this example
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-using-url-query-string.html

Comment: If the window is defined in a content template, why can't you just set the value on page_load to whatever you need it to be?  Controls in the radwindow are accessible from anywhere in the codebehind. Can you provide your code if I'm not understanding something...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all you need is included in the partial rendering. Probably, the content you updated on the server simply did not travel to the client.

In case you use regular asp:UpdatePanels you may need to call their Update() method.

If you are using RadAjax, add an AjaxSetting where the buttons/controls in the RadWindow are initiators and the updated controls are the one(s) you need or their container.